# I just updated Android Studio to 4.0 from 3.6 and I get the error Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.6.4

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've looked at many posts online and I can't fix this issue. I have tried to enter Gradle commands and cmd will not recognize them. I have tried to update gradle.properties and fix the distributionUrl but that does not change the error message. I do not know what else to try. I have even tried deleting and reinstalling android studio but that does not work either. Can anyone offer any help please? Or perhaps even point me to a similar question that has been answered? Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147493/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open File---Project Structure and change the gradle version.
[image]

Then sync project with gradle files again.