# Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 6.1.1. Please fix the project's Gradle settings

Tags: android, gradle

I had previously the Android Studio 3.5.2 and everything was working perfectly. When I upgraded to Android Studio 4.1.3 following error started hitting whenever I build/run the project:

The minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. The current version is 6.1.1.  Please fix the project's Gradle settings.

I have installed the currently available latest Gradle 6.8.3, but still, it is showing the same error. Please help.

Regards,
Sarib Shamim.

Comment: Did you change the gradle version in your project? Or just upgraded it on your machine? Check your `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: #Tue Mar 23 15:59:30 PKT 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip

Comment: Above is the text from gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: I have downloaded the latest Gradle 6.8.3, also edited system variable PATH for gradle, then changed the gradle-wrapper.properties from Android Studio. Still, there is an error. Plz guide me what to do now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.1.1. Current version is 5.6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147493/minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-6-1-1-current-version-is-5-6-4)

Comment: Yes, I have found the answer (just after few days I posted the question). It was about the gradle upgrade only. Thank you very much.

Comment: You dont have to upgrade the gradle version. Remember: there is a gradle plugin which have a version, and your project have a gradle version. Some gradle plugins dont support old gradle versions. Just change gradle plugin and it detects your project gradle file. To do that: android studio >> file >> project structure >> chose different gradle plugin version

Answer (score 0):

After read different resources and try different approaches with no lock, I decided to reinstall Android Studio (which was a tricky process due to different folders related), I tried to reinstall it from a PPA repo, using snap and even using an official tar.gz file and still the same problem with the gradle version.

So I deleted my source code repo and then I cloned it again -fortunatelly I didn't update my github repo after the gradle's update, after that, I started Android Studio and now everything is working.

Again, the key was to have an stable version of my code before the gradle's plugin update.