# How do I resolve the a build exception failure in Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have been trying to run my flutter app through an emulator but I end up getting an error in the app/build.gradle section. Below is the error message, any insights to this will help

- What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Failed to apply plugin 'kotlin-android'. > The current Gradle version 6.7 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 6.7.1 or newer, or the previous version of the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62147493/minimum-supported-gradle-version-is-6-1-1-current-version-is-5-6-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to android folder in the project ==> gradle ==> gradle-wrapper.properties
then change the distributionUrl to
==> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip